# How do I use Setup Project with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, crystal-reports

This is the first time I am doing this.

I have built a software. I will be using a setup package from Visual Studio. I think I will be using the Setup Project which Builds an installer for a Windows-based application as my project has been built on Window Forms. I have included Crystal Reports. As it current stands I have method in my application when a user clicks on the button the reports is displayed. In that method the .rpt file path is showing as....

```
 cryRpt.Load("C:\\MyFolder\\MyFolder\\ProjectName\\FolderName\\HRMS\\HRMS\\Report.rpt"); // this is from my PC.
```

So my question is what do I need to know to setup the correct .rpt file path. where ever it is going to be installed?

For clarification I need to install Crystal Reports on Clients PC? http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0.exe

because I looked at this thread... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465170/crystal-report-integration-issue-on-setup-and-deployment)

Do I need to do anything else on Client's PC?

I am not sure if I am going to run into a problem related to this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870020/crystal-reports-not-working-after-creating-project-setup) I have hard code the path, any advice?

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me here.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

private void btnReportA_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load("C:\\MyFolder\\MyFolder\\ProjectName\\FolderName\\HRMS\\HRMS\\Report.rpt");
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }

 public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
    public MainForm()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  
       Source=C:\MyFolder\MyFolder\ProjectName\FolderName\database.mdb");
       crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```

**update 1 with a solution-ish**

I was looked at crystal reports dynamic path and I changed from the line of code from...

```
cryRpt.Load("C:\\MyFolder\\MyFolder\\ProjectName\\FolderName\\HRMS\\HRMS\\Report.rpt");
```

to

```
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Report.rpt");
```

Then move the rpt files in bin\Debug

You can find your bin/Debug file location by using the following code...

```
TextBox1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
().Location);
```

Which I got from this website.

I think the above is a solution.

I will give an update 2 whenever I discovered how to use the Setup Project with Crystal Reports because I may or may not need to update on client's PC.

It took few hours to figure this out.

**Update 2**
I will open a new thread. I think update 1 is not really a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always add the report to your project and then reference it like `"~\Report.rpt"`.
As far as deploying the runtime, read this [wiki](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Deploying+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Runtime) from SAP on runtime deployment.

Comment: thanks Capagnolo. I think I should look into dynamic path area. So if I can I like to close this tread and work on dynamic path and If I have problems I like to open a new thread.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Always open a new thread for a new question.